# Zend Framework 2 Form creation via Factory. How to remove elements from fieldset depending on role?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am creating a form using factories and specified form structure by configuring Fieldsets.

However, user with the role "**admin**" may edit form with all fields of an Entity and regular user "**client**" edit just few fields. That is why I have to delete elements from fieldsets in controller.

```
    $this->form->getBaseFieldset()->remove('name');
    $this->form->getBaseFieldset()->remove('title');
    $this->form->getBaseFieldset()->remove('message');`
```

Is it possible to specify in Fieldset or Form configuration for what role element must be added or deleted?

```
class ZoneDefaultElement extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{

    public function __construct($name, $entity)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => Element\Text::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Title',
                'label_attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label required',
                ],
            ],
        ], ['priority' => 1])
     };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of the constructor can be anything (in fact in `Fieldset` it is an empty `array` if not given), so you should be able to just pass in an array of items to use:

```
class ZoneDefaultElement extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{

    public function __construct($name, $options)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $entity = $options['entity'];
        $user = $options['user'];

        // Standard element
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'title',
            'type' => Element\Text::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Title',
                'label_attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label required',
                ],
            ],
        ], ['priority' => 1]);

        if ($user->isAdmin()) {
            // Add "admin-only" elements
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for quick answer. I have figured out own solution. If you are interested...

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided above is pretty ok. If system is not very large and contains few elements in forms it is possible to maintain it. As fare as system is a little bit complex I decided to provide more OOP solution.

```
class ZoneDefaultElement extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct($name, $entity)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'title',
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Title',                  
            ],
        ], ['priority' => 1, 'access' => ['allow' => ['admin'])
     }
};
```

And deny configuration will be like this :

```
        $this->add([
          'name' => 'message',            
          'options' => [
            'label' => 'Message',              
          ],
        ], ['priority' => 1, 'access' => ['deny' => ['guest'])
```

I have added one more layer between Fieldset and my custom fieldsets:

```
class ExtendedFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    public $formMiddleware;

    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    public function add($elementOrFieldset, array $flags = [])
    {
        if (array_key_exists('access', $flags)) {
            if(!$this->getFormMiddleware()->filter($flags['access'])){
                return false;
            };
        }
        parent::add($elementOrFieldset, $flags);
    }

    public function setFormMiddleware(FormMiddleware $formMiddleware)
    {
        $this->formMiddleware = $formMiddleware;
    }

    public function getFormMiddleware()
    {
        if (!$this->formMiddleware) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("FormMiddleware not specified");
        }
        return $this->formMiddleware;
    }
}
```

Now we have to extend from this ExtendedFiedset witch overwrites parent add() method and has setter and getter for middleware where filter logic realized.

```
class UserFieldset extends ExtendedFieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entity, FormMiddleware $formMiddleware)
    {
        $this->setFormMiddleware($formMiddleware);

        parent::__construct('fieldset');

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'email',
            'type' => Element\Email::class,
            'attributes' => [
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'required'  => 'required',
            ],
            'options' => [
                'label' => 'Email:',
                'label_attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'col-sm-4 control-label required',
                ],
            ],
        ], ['priority' => 1, ['access' => ['deny' => ['guest']]]]);
  }
```

}

And finally FormMiddleware:

```
class FormMiddleware
{
    private $authenticationService;

    public function __construct(AuthenticationServiceInterface $service)
    {
        $this->authenticationService = $service;
    }

    private function getUserRole() : string
    {
        $this->getIdentity()->getRole();                
    }

    public function getIdentity()
    {
        $identity = $this->authenticationService->getIdentity();
        return $identity;
    }

    public function filter(array $resource = [])
    {
        $marker = true;
        if(!empty($resource)){

            if(array_key_exists('deny', $resource)){
                if(in_array($this->getUserRole(), $resource['deny'])){
                    $marker = false;
                }else{
                    $marker = true;
                }
            }

            if(array_key_exists('allow', $resource)) {
                if(in_array($this->getUserRole(), $resource['allow'])){
                    $marker = true;
                }else{
                    $marker = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return $marker;
    }
}
```

It depends on project structure, I hope an idea is clear...